# How do I send a notify OSD message to a remote user via ssh?

Tags: 12.04, ssh, notify-osd

Sometimes we need to send a message to a remote user. We can display messages on our local desktop using Notify OSD, but we are unable to send a message to the remote user's desktop.

We tried the following:

```
ssh user@remote   
notify-send message
```

-> Sends message to the local display but not to the remote.

```
ssh admin@remote
sudo -u user "notify-send message"
sudo: notify-send user: command not found
```

-> There was a command not found error.

```
ssh -X user@remote "DISPLAY=:0 notify-send message"
```

-> Again sends the message to my local box only.

Is there any way to send a message to the remote desktop?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have you tried

`ssh user@host 'DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "TEST MESSAGE."'`

Answer taken from
[ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240828](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240828) (without the `-X` option as suggested by [jjmontes](https://askubuntu.com/users/44592/jjmontes))

Comment: -X is not needed since we are not forwarding the X protocol, but instead enforcing DISPLAY=:0 which is local to the remote host.

Comment: @jjmontes I tested it and you're right. Fixed.