# Can I send a message through a network?

Tags: networking

How can I send a message to all Ubuntu Desktops in my network, as with net send * in Windows?

Is there any tip other than installing an application on both sides?

Is it possible to send a message to a specific IP?

Comment: in case you can SSH into these boxes you could send them an OSD notification, but this can not be done to all connected users without writing a script. http://askubuntu.com/questions/132592/how-do-i-send-a-notify-osd-message-to-a-remote-user-via-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no service similar to "net send".

Comment: thanks for you response , but as you say there is no solution ?

Comment: @nux, that is correct.