# Send broadcast pop-up message to all network Ubuntu systems

Tags: networking, notification

In my office environment I need to send a GUI pop-up message
to all of the Ubuntu desktop clients in my network.

Is there any application I can use to do this?

Comment: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/187022/how-can-i-send-a-custom-desktop-notification and http://askubuntu.com/questions/132592/how-do-i-send-a-notify-osd-message-to-a-remote-user-via-ssh

Answer (score 3):

You could send via SSH a notify popup, assuming sshpass is installed on the host and ssh/notify on both host/client

```
sshpass -p password ssh -X user@10.0.0.5 "DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "My message...""
```

where you'd substitute your own password, user, IP address and message.

Comment: But "notify" is a GUI popup ;-)  and `notify-send -i {deal.ico} {message}` will also use an icon in front of the message.